# LinkedList add() append null instead of value 15

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

Using LinkedList to populate a stack of Long type elements. For some reason, value null is added instead of 15 when I call my push method. Why is that?

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class LongStack {

   public static void main (String[] argum) {
      LongStack s = new LongStack();
      s.push(15);
      System.out.println(s);
   }
   
   private LinkedList<Long> l;

   LongStack() {
      l = new LinkedList<Long>();
   }

   public void push (long a) {
      l.add(a);
   }
```

OK, i found the problem. My bad. There was an overriding toString method (`return null;`) later in my code that wasn't implemented. But thanks for the tips.

Comment: Where do you see null is added ? Your code works

Comment: Don't name all of your variables `l`. That makes it hard to determine which `l` is being operated on.

Comment: I can't reproduce the behaviour you describe. The code works. I only had to change how the linkedlist is printed because simply feeding it to a `System.out.println()` didn't print its contents.

Comment: https://pastebin.pl/view/ef437ecf

Comment: LinkedList is a generic typed class so it should be created as `LinkedList<Long>` assuming the type you want is `long`.